# Low dimensional homotopy fibration TOP(M) -> TOP(int(M))

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, cobordism

In the thesis of Nancy Cardim she proves that for $M$ a topological manifold of dim $\geq 5$ with connected boundary, there exists a homotopy fiber sequence

$C(\partial M)\rightarrow  TOP(M) \rightarrow TOP(int(M))$

where $C(\partial M)$ is the concordance space of $\partial M$. Is there an obvious reason/counter-example as to why this should/should not exist for lower dimensional manifolds?

Reference for dim $\geq 5$:
N.Cardim, Embeddings of open manifolds, Thesis, Notre Dame University 1993.
Available here: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cardim.pdf
Or here: Transactions of the AMS, Volume 351, Number 6, Pages 2353–2373

Comment: Which definition are you using for $TOP(int(M))$? It's an open manifold so there are a variety of ways of considering this object as a space.

Comment: @Ryan I'm considering _TOP(M)_ (resp., _TOP(int(M))_) as the simplicial group of homeomorphisms of _M_ (resp., _int(M)_), precisely as defined in the cited paper.  My question is simply whether it is reasonable to hope a version of  Theorem B in the cited paper holds for manifolds of all dimensions. I realize some of her proof techniques don't go through, but it seems to me the result should still hold in lower dimensions. (I'm not looking for a proof that it does, I'm just wondering if there is an obvious obstruction that someone more knowledgable than I may see).

Comment: It appears plausible in dimension $2$ and $3$, because these concordence spaces are contractible.  In dimension $4$ it's unclear to me how plausible the result might be as I know very little about homeomorphisms of $4$-manifolds.

Comment: @Ryan That sits with my (limited) intuition as well. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Cardim gives an example (at the end of $\S$ 3) in dimension 2 that illustrates the TOP map need not be a Kan fibration.

Comment: Thanks, but the claim isn't asking for that map to be a fibration, just that the homotopy fiber is the desired concordance space, so I don't think this gives a counterexample to my question. (I don't *think* Cardim gives this example as an illustration of dimensional problems, rather a warning that she isn't claiming the map need ever be a fibration on the nose-- but maybe I misunderstand).